# How to properly show an element after applying display:none with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm running into a really tough issue where I'm unable to trigger a dropdown menu after adding display:none via a click event. I previously tried adding it back with a hover event but that seemed to trigger all the time in certain browsers so I've abandoned that and am completely stuck. With the following code, how would I properly show the dropdown once again after the display property has been switched.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown a').click(function() { 
        if($("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").css("display", "block")){
           $("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").hide();
        }
    });
})
```

Apologies for asking a similar question earlier but I didn't really understand the problem before. If I'm out of line, I apologize but I'm really stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it would be better if you have posted css/html codes..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to just use `.toggle()`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown a').click(function() { 
        $("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").toggle();
    });
})
```

It automatically checks if the element is visible and then *toggles* the display property.

Comment: This works initially but then once an item in the dropdown is clicked the menu won't show up again. I'm running into the issue only on Chrome on Windows and FF. It's driving me mad and I'm guessing that something else is the culprit at this point. I've tried all the other suggestions provided and I get largely the same result. 

What should happen is on this page: http://development.maclynutility.com/littlefriends/childrens-services the user should be able to navigate up and down with the submenu not constantly showing and I'm stuck on how to get that to happen.

Comment: Looks like the use of .toggle causes the issue across all browsers. I've implemented it on the site now instead of the code I posted originally.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use show() function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown a').click(function() { 
        if($("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").css("display", "block")){
           $("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").hide();
        }
       else if($("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").css("display", "none")){
           $("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, in general, it's better to do this stuff by adding classes in css. You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown a').click(function() { 
    $("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").toggleClass("show");
});
});
```

and in css:

```
.show {
  display:block;
}
```

Of course, using .show() and .hide() are also viable. It just gives you less control.